# How can I force doxygen to generate deterministic, readable URLs?

Tags: doxygen

I'd like my documentation to have deterministic urls, and (preferably readable) for our doc writers to link to.

Here is an example of what I don't want:
https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.13.11/d7/d76/class_aws_1_1_client_1_1_a_w_s_client.html

Each time I publish a new build, the urls change.

Here is a link to my current doxygen config:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/doxygen/doxygen.config

Any ideas?

Comment: As I understand it correctly  refer to the d7/d76 part of the url, these are a consequence of CREATE_SUBDIRS and present so that not too many files land in a directory (performance). A bit strange that these values change, they should only change when a filename changes. (write all your documentation in doxygen and you can link directly to most item ;-) )

Comment: ah!  I see. So is this caused by CREATE_SUBDIRS ?

Comment: @albert. I think the answer is for me to turn off CREATE_SUBDIRS. If you add it, I can accept it and close this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this was to turn off CREATE_SUBDIRS.